# как создать очередь из записей?

Tags: python, django

В общем когда я экспереминтировал с возможностями Django у меня возник вопрос каким образом я моггу добавить очередь для записей моделей, например у меня есть пару блоков и мне нужно что бы на первом блоке у меня выводилась модель которая была зарегистрированна первой а на втором блоке должна выводится следующая запись. Каким образом я могу это сделать ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример query_set

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'article/sale.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

    def get_queryset(self):
    return Goods.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
```

Comment: Например, выдавать QuerySet с параметром order_by('id'). И тут еще завязка на вёрстку, кода которой нет в вопросе.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Какую именно вёрстку ? Простите я новичок и не особо силён в терменах, то что я добавил является тем что вы желаете ?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Вы мне поможете ? хотя бы материалами